# Kubernetes : Dynamic Persistent Volume provisioning using NFS

Tags: docker, kubernetes, nfs

I have multi node kubernetes setup. I am trying to allocate a Persistent volume dynamically using storage classes with NFS volume plugin. 
I found storage classes examples for glusterfs, aws-ebs, etc.but, I didn't find any example for NFS.
If I create PV and PVC only then NFS works very well(Without storage class).
I tried to write storage class file for NFS, by referring other plugins. please refer it below,

nfs-storage-class.yaml

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  namespace: kube-system
  name: my-storage
  annotations:
    storageclass.beta.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"

provisioner: kubernetes.io/nfs
parameters:
  path: /nfsfileshare
  server: <nfs-server-ip>
```

nfs-pv-claim.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: demo-claim
  annotations:
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: my-storage
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

It didn't worked. So, my question is, Can we write a storage class for NFS? Does it support dynamic provisioing?

Comment: Here is one example with cinder plugin http://theearlybirdtechnology.com/2017/09/03/using-dynamic-persistent-storage-cinder-plugin-host-mounting-docker-container-data-storage-kubernetes/

Answer (score 7):

As of August 2020, here's how things look for NFS persistence on Kubernetes:

You can

- Put an NFS volume on a Pod directly:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: k8s.gcr.io/test-webserver
    name: test-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /test-pd
      name: test-volume
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    nfs:
      path: /foo/bar
      server: wherever.dns
```

- Manually create a Persistent Volume backed by NFS, and mount it with a Persistent Volume Claim (PV spec shown below):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv0003
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  storageClassName: slow
  mountOptions:
  - hard
  - nfsvers=4.1
  nfs:
    path: /tmp
    server: 172.17.0.2
```

- Use the (now deprecated) [NFS PV provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/external-storage/tree/master/nfs) from `external-storage`. This was last updated two years ago, and has been officially EOL'd, so good luck. With this route, you can make a Storage Class such as the one below to fulfill PVCs from your NFS server.

  - **Update:** There is a new incarnation of this provisioner as [`kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner`!](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner) It seems to work in a similar way to the old `nfs-client` provisioner, but is much more up-to-date. Huzzah!

```yaml
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: example-nfs
provisioner: example.com/nfs
mountOptions:
- vers=4.1
```

- Evidently, CSI is the future, and [there is a NFS CSI driver.](https://github.com/kubernetes-csi/csi-driver-nfs) However, it doesn't support dynamic provisioning yet, so it's not really terribly useful.

  - **Update (December 2020):** Dynamic provisioning is apparently in the works (on `master`, but not released) for the CSI driver.
- You might be able to replace `external-storage`'s NFS provisioner with something from the community, or something you write. In researching this problem, I stumbled on [a provisioner written by someone on GitHub,](https://github.com/juliohm1978/kubernetes-nfs-volume-provisioner) for example. Whether such provisioners perform well, are secure, or work at all is beyond me, but they do exist.

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking into doing the same thing. I found https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/tree/master/nfs, which I think you based your provisioner on?

I think an nfs provider would need to create a unique directory under the path defined. I'm not really sure how this could be done.

Maybe this is better of as an github issue on the kubernetes repo.

Comment: yes I tried the external-storage nfs provisioner, but it didn't worked for me. Container was giving some error. I didn't get time to debug it. but I ll try sometime after

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic storage provisioning using NFS doesn't work, better use glusterfs. There's a good tutorial with fixed to common problems while setting up.
http://blog.lwolf.org/post/how-i-deployed-glusterfs-cluster-to-kubernetes/

Comment: Now kubernetes supports NFS directly.

Comment: what does this mean? We can use NFS in PC Claims now?

Comment: Yes, we can directly specify nfs ip and path in the pv.

Answer (score 2):

I also tried to enable the NFS provisioner on my kubernetes cluster and at first it didn't work, because the quickstart guide does not mention that you need to apply the rbac.yaml as well (I opened a [PR](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/pull/1116) to fix this).

The nfs provisioner works fine for me if I follow these steps on my cluster:
https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/tree/master/nfs#quickstart

```
$ kubectl create -f deploy/kubernetes/deployment.yaml
$ kubectl create -f deploy/kubernetes/rbac.yaml
$ kubectl create -f deploy/kubernetes/class.yaml
```

Then you should be able to create PVCs like this:

```
$ kubectl create -f deploy/kubernetes/claim.yaml
```

You might want to change the folders used for the volume mounts in `deployment.yaml` to match it with your cluster.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `StorageClass` is to *create* storage, e.g. from cloud providers (or "Provisioner" as they call it in the kubernetes docs). In case of NFS you only want to get *access* to existing storage and there is no creation involved. Thus you don't need a `StorageClass`. Please refer to this [blog](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2017/03/dynamic-provisioning-and-storage-classes-kubernetes/).

Comment: What if you don't want to create a nfs folder manually for each pvc? Lets say you have a statefullset and each replica has its nfs pvc for example

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AWS, I believe you can use this image to create a NFS server:

https://hub.docker.com/r/alphayax/docker-volume-nfs