# Run NFS-Server on local kubernetes cluster?

Tags: docker, centos, kubernetes, centos7, nfs

Can anyone share a working example of the nfs server on the local kubernetes cluster?
TODO.
Run nfs-server on my kubernetes cluster and use to bind the nodes to use Persistence Volumes.

[A similar theme.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51085188/using-nfs-network-path-as-a-kubernetes-persistence-volume)

[Did not really understand how to install.](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/tree/master/nfs-client/deploy)

[I started and I broke the cluster. Could not remove the replication controller.](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/volumes/nfs/nfs-server-rc.yaml)

I will be grateful for the help.

Comment: _Can anyone share a working example of the nfs server on the local kubernetes cluster_ do you mean an NFS server **in** the cluster, or an NFS server that merely runs on the same Nodes as the rest of your containers? Either way, that's pretty weird given that NFS is sharing access to local disks, but if the disks are local to the Nodes, then, uh, don't use NFS, right?

Comment: I mean an NFS server in the cluster.